# Getting unique elements from two lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames,

```
df1 <- data.frame(gene = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen4"))

df2 <- data.frame(gene = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen5"))
```

I would like to extract the unique elements of each list, so I end up with another two data frames

```
df3 <- data.frame(gene = c("Gen4"))

df4 <- data.frame(gene = c("Gen5"))
```

Thanks in advance, Jose.

Comment: Use the `anti_join()` function from the `dplyr` package.  It's description is for this specific purpose.

Comment: `df3 <- anti_join(df1, df2)` and `df4 <- anti_join(df2, df1)`.